# Compiling to ES6 instead Typescript - JHipster React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, jhipster

I've set up app using JHipster / React.

The only thing I would like to change is not using typescript. Is there solution for that?

Regards!

Comment: Not supported by JHipster, so you have to make it manually which means you can forget about using generated code for frontend, in such case you should consider not generating it at all using --skip-client option. Or you configure typescript to transpile to ES6

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, it would be great if you posted your answer as an answer so this question could be resolved.

Comment: Well at that time, I did not consider it as a helpful answer and never got feedback from this user, so  now 18 months later it's just not worth it.